# I can't figure out this word? (sorry this isn't my native language)

Tags: riddle, word

I'm trying to figure out a word, but I just can't find a proper one. Can you help me out please?

My suffix, well I guess that's something a lot of people on this site do on and off.
And my infix is a...... uhhh sorry I'll think about if there's a better way to describe it.
Finally, I suppose my prefix is a little touch and go... and that's about it.

Sorry if the hints are not useful, my whole is something I'm not so fluent with.

Comment: Interesting puzzle :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Is it:

> [Tagalog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagalog_language)

I suppose my prefix is a little touch and go

> The game of **tag**

And my infix is a...... uhhh sorry I'll think about if there's a better way to describe it.

> The infix is literally "**a**", as stated

My suffix, well I guess that's something a lot of people on this site do on and off.

> Users of this site **log** on and off

My whole is something I'm not so fluent with

> Perhaps you are trying to learn Tagalog?

*Additional notes after the solution was verified:*

> - "(sorry this isn't my native language)" is an extra hint that the answer is a language, nice misdirection
>  - "my whole is something I'm not so fluent with" doesn't even have to mean that the author is trying to learn the language - just that they don't know it.
>  - "...and that's about it" is another hint about the game of tag

Comment: great answer and explanation. I was afraid that the one part you didn't explain would make the riddle too easy (you'll know which part I mean), but it seems that nobody else caught on.

Comment: Nice edit. There were two more micro-hints left, by the way. One is about the whole, the other about the prefix.

Comment: Got the prefix one, but can't figure out anything more with the whole. Will keep puzzling over it!

Comment: I can confirm that your prefix hint is correct.

Comment: Is the other hint the fact that it's a "cebcre" abha? (rot13)

Answer (score 17):

Not positive, but I think the word you're looking for might be

> **Communication**

My prefix is touch and go.

> **Comm** - a shorthand for a push-to-talk headset, i.e. "dual-comm". You touch a button on the comm when you want to use it, and let it go when you're done. Hence "touch and go." ([Example](http://atlanticsignal.com/products/invictus-single-comm-push-to-talk/))

My suffix is something a lot of people on this site do on and off.

> **Munication** - a slangy word for speaking in a bizarre, cryptic way so that no one understands what you're saying. Obviously users on Puzzling SE do this a lot! ([Source](https://definithing.com/munication/)) ([Source](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=munication))

My infix... uh I'll think of a better way to describe it.

> **Mm** - a thinking sound.

My whole is something I'm not very good at.

> **Communication** - you're saying that you're not so good at communicating clues!

Comment: wow this is very well thought-out answer! I like your interpretation of the prefix and suffix. Regrettably, the solution is something else.

Comment: @kedarguru Dang, I was so sure I had it!

Comment: @Sciborg So sure, but not positive?

Comment: they'd taken a drug test just prior to submitting the riddle and wanted us to know the result

Comment: @kedarguru I wasn't 100% sure it was the answer, but it lined up so well and seemed to match all the clues. I guess I got a bit too creative!

Comment: Being creative is definitely no fault - I know many Rileys on here do require more than an everyday vocabulary. If you come across another riddle from me,